# How can i save API response data as a variable in ReactJS so i can import it in any components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am following the following tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-axios-react

I am trying to import a value from an API endpoint and save it as a variable in another component.

My API endpoint is very simple compared to the example, it just responds with this:

```
{"USD":1168.64}
```

I have made a new component called PersonList.js like in the tutorial:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://myendpoint.com`)
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          this.state.persons
            .map(person =>
              <li key={person.id}>{person.name}</li>
            )
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

and then in another component i have i am importing it like this:

```
import PersonList from './components/PersonList.js';
```

however i cannot console.log the variable PersonList.

I understand there is 2 issues here:

1. my PersonList.js is not setup to get just the USD value from the API
2. i dont know how to save the API response as a variable once its imported.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You are importing a component, not a variable. Components are used to draw things on the screen

Comment: I'm a little confused. Your components/state are _person-based_ and yet the data you're getting is about _currency_. Also: your API response is a single object, and you won't be able to `map` over that. _"i dont know how to save the API response as a variable once its imported."_: you _are_ saving the data but you're saving it to state. So, ultimately, I'm not really clear what your question is.

Comment: @Andy i am just trying to save the USD value from api endpoint  as a variable that i can console.log to display the USD:* value

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using class components you'll need to use the [`componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) which will allow you to do something once the component has been updated/the state has been changed.

The previous props and state are passed as arguments to the method, and it's a good idea to use a condition to double check that things have changed so that you don't do any unnecessary work.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { persons: {} };
  }

  // Fake API request
  componentDidMount() {
    const persons = { usd: 1168.64 };
    this.setState({ persons });
  }

  // Has the state changed?
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.persons !== this.state.persons) {
      console.log(this.state.persons.usd);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Initial render
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```